# HP 15 TouchSmart Notebook PC trackpad does not work. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hp, touchscreen, trackpad

I just installed ubuntu on an HP 15 TouchSmart Notebook PC model: 15-d021ca. The trackpad does not work but an external mouse does. xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version. The touch screen also does not work for scrolling unless you click on the actual scroll bar.

I have tried sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-two-finger-scroll-touchsmart-tm2.conf

then adding:

Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "enable synaptics SHMConfig" 
   MatchIsTouchpad "on"
   MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
   Driver "synaptics"
   Option "SHMConfig" "on"
   Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "5"
   Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "60"
   Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1"
   Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1"
EndSection

but it won't allow me to save it.